# Probability of i > j, double summation

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I am trying to find the probability of one discrete random variable, $i$, being greater than discrete random variable, $j$.

The probability of $j$ taking a particular integer value $\{-c, -c + 2, \text{...} , c - 2, c\}$, given $t_1$, and $p$, where $t_1$ is one of the possible integers $\{-c, -c + 2, \text{...} , c - 2, c\}$, and where $0\leq p\leq 1$, is given by:

```
\[Alpha][j_] := Sum[Binomial[(1/2)*(c + Subscript[t, 1]), k]*
   p^(2*k - (1/2)*(i + Subscript[t, 1]))*
   Binomial[(1/2)*(c - Subscript[t, 1]), (c + i)/2 - k]*
   (1 - p)^(c - (2*k - (1/2)*(i + Subscript[t, 1]))), 
 {k, Max[0, (1/2)*(i + Subscript[t, 1])], 
   Min[(c + i)/2, (1/2)*(c + Subscript[t, 1])]}]
```

while the probability of $i$ taking a particular integer value $\{-c, -c + 2, \text{...} , c - 2, c\}$, given $t_2$, and $p$, where $t_2$ is one of the possible integers $\{-c, -c + 2, \text{...} , c - 2, c\}$, is given by:

```
\[Beta][i_] := Sum[Binomial[(1/2)*(c + Subscript[t, 2]), k]*
   p^(2*k - (1/2)*(i + Subscript[t, 2]))*
   Binomial[(1/2)*(c - Subscript[t, 2]), (c + i)/2 - k]*
   (1 - p)^(c - (2*k - (1/2)*(i + Subscript[t, 2]))), 
 {k, Max[0, (1/2)*(i + Subscript[t, 2])], 
   Min[(c + i)/2, (1/2)*(c + Subscript[t, 2])]}]
```

My approach to solving this problem is shown below. My problem is that I can't seem to formulate the final expression using Mathematica. Or, perhaps my problem is deeper yet. In any case, I am looking for help using Mathematica on this problem:[image]

```
Sum[\[Beta][i_]*\[Alpha][j_], {i, c, -c + 2}, {j, i - c, -c}], in steps of -2
```

Comment: Functions should be input as Wolfram Language code, not LaTeX.  Edit your question, copy and paste in the code, select the block of code, then use the `{}` button to format the code. Also, post code, not pictures of code.

Comment: Edmund, I hope this suffices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `WeightedData` to construct an `EmpiricalDistribution` and then frame your problem as an inequality using `Probability`.

First realise that you only need define on probability mass function.  This can be done by using parameters instead of relying on global variables.  Use your `α` definition:

```
pmf[c_, t_, p_, x_] := 
 Sum[Binomial[(c + t)/2, k] p^(2 k - (x + t)/2 ) 
     Binomial[(c - t)/2, (c + x)/2 - k] 
     (1 - p)^(c - (2 k - (x + t)/2)), 
   {k, Max[0, (x + t)/2], Min[(c + x)/2, (c + t)/2]}]
```

The PMF looks good; sums to 1 and positive over the domain.

```
With[{c = 5},
 Sum[pmf[c, -3, .5, x], {x, -c, c, 2}]
 ]
```

> ```
> 1.
> ```

```
With[{c = 5},
 DiscretePlot[pmf[c, -3, .5, x], {x, -c, c, 2}]
 ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

The PMF can be used to create an `EmpiricalDistribution`. Create a distribution for `i` and `j`. I used `c = 5` and `p = .5` for both with `t1 = -3` and `t2 = -1`.

```
With[{c = 5},
 iDist = EmpiricalDistribution@WeightedData[Range[-c, c, 2], pmf[c, -3, .5, #] &];
 jDist = EmpiricalDistribution@WeightedData[Range[-c, c, 2], pmf[c, -1, .5, #] &];
 ]
```

Next use `Probability` to evaluate your result.

```
Probability[i > j, {i \[Distributed] iDist, j \[Distributed] jDist}]
```

> ```
> 0.376953
> ```

I also tried using `ProbabilityDistribution` on the PMF but it would not cooperate so went for `EmpiricalDistribution`. The `ProbabilityDistribution` approach would allow for symbolic evaluation and I have gone out to WRI to find out why this PMF does not cooperate. Perhaps the above is all you need.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your instructive answer, Edmund. This certainly helps me a lot. Of course, it would have been ideal if ProbabilityDistribution worked here. What, by the way is WRI?

Comment: @user120911 WRI = Wolfram Research Inc.

Comment: thank you. That is much appreciated. I would be very interested to hear what they say about this problem.

Comment: Did you ever hear from WRI about why Mathematica had trouble with the PMF?